# Bulk Inserting data from Flat File to Database Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Flat File with the following data:

```
productID,productName,cost
1234,Plasme TV,15000
1234,DVDPlayer,Mixer Grinder,7000
```

This example is based upon as the store has come up with an offer saying whoever buys a Plasma TV, gets a DVDPlayer and Mixer Grinder worth 7000 free. So the store wants this Flat File to be dumped into a table with the productID being the same and the table should look something like this:

```
productID    productName              cost
1234         Plasma TV                15000
1234         DVDPlayer,Mixer Grinder  7000
```

that is, in the first row in the product column Plasma TV should come and in the second row, in the productName column, both DVDPlayer and Mixer Grinder should come together.

Can anyone please help me with it??

I need to write a Stored Procedure using T-SQL for this.

Thanks

Comment: how do you determine which one is the first row - therefore know which one is the product on offer?

Comment: Personally I'd introduce a 2nd table to hold the *offer* information - So your original *product* table has 3 rows (not 2), one for each product. The *offer* table has the columns *offer product id* and *gift product id* and would contain 2 rows to represent the assoication of the free gifts...

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the suggestion. I know that using a third table would solve the problem. but is there anyway by which I can do something as per my requirements??

Comment: Oh, you poor thing... Personally, I would try to find the guy who did this to me... and be rude to him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not-nice to have commas in fields in a comma-delimited file.  There may be some way to approach this with a fancy format file.  My recommendation is to load the data into a staging table with a single character column and no delimiter.

Then, you can load your final table as:

```
insert into t(productID, productName, cost)
    select cast(left(st.line, 4) as int) as ProductId,
           substring(st.line, 6, len(st.line) - 5 - charindex(',', reverse(st.line))) as ProductName,
           cast(right(st.line, charindex(',', reverse(st.line))-1) as float) as cost
    from stagingTable st;
```

This is using string manipulation to pull out the different fields from each line.

Answer (score 0):

Your database design is way beyond optimal. What I’d really recommend here is that you consider updating storage tables.

“1234,DVDPlayer,Mixer Grinder,7000” – how does this tell you which DVDPlayer specifically and which Grinder specifically? What if store has more than one DVD Player model in stock?

If you can’t update tables then at least consider storing product IDs instead of product names.